# Tools for Making MySQL Table Schema Changes?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL, but I have a pretty basic need, and somewhat surprised that I can't find any clear answer after googling a bit.

My webapp uses a mysql database.  Suppose I need to add a new column to an table that has existing data.  What is the best way to do this?  Are there any tools to make this easy and safe?

Should I:

- make a "hot" change and add the new column to the production table?
- or create a new table, copy the data from the old table to the new table, and then delete the old table?
- or any other way?

I have looked at MySQL Workbench.  But it's not clear that it can do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Log into the database. Issue the [appropriate command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html). Don't use GUI tools until you understand how your rmdbs works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Workbench can do that. HeidiSQL is also a nice tool. Just make a backup before changing production schema. No need to copy the data around.

Comment: @BoristheSpider IMHO the best/easiest way to learn DDL is to use a GUI and let it show you, what code will be executed.

Comment: I'll second what @PaulSpiegel said, I think the fact that Workbench shows you the SQL it's about to run is a great learning opportunity.  Anyway, it *should* be perfectly safe to add a column to a table that already has data, but if you're nervous you can always make a backup copy in case you need to restore it (similar to your 2nd bullet) or use mysqldump (or Workbench itself) to create a database dump file that you can restore if needed.  Naturally, you should already be creating regular backups of your database anyway...